# Side bar menu not creating

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website using Django . Below is my code.

sidebar-menu.css:

```css
.sidebar-menu>li:hover>a, .sidebar-menu>li.active>a {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
.sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 0 1px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

My error is side-bar menu is not working. I am sure that there is no error in HTML code  . Kindly help me if there is any error in css.

Here is my html code:

```
{% block termscondobs %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'terms-conditions' %}" class="waves-effect">
      <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> <span>Terms & Conditions</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left float-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
      <li><a href="{% url 'terms-conditions' %}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i> OBS T&C</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'terms-febs' %}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i> Febs T&C</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'terms-febs-events' %}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i> Febs Events T&C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endblock %}
```

I am new to Front End. So any help would be great.

Comment: you have display:none on your css.This will hide the submenu

Comment: Yep, just remove that and try again